# Getting 'LinAlgError: Eigenvalues did not converge' when running factor analysis

Tags: python, numpy, factor-analysis

select the dataset and standardise the dataset and update the standardised dataset in new dataframe

```
credit_seg_new.columns ## new dataset
```

```
data_scaled
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
data_scaled = sc.fit_transform(credit_seg_new)
```

then finding the correlation of that standardised dataset

```
corrl=pd.DataFrame(data_scaled).corr()
corrl
```

I got the eigen value and cum_variance of that correlation

```
eigen_values = np.linalg.eigvals(corrl)
eigen_values_cumvar = (eigen_values/corrl.shape[0]).cumsum()
pd.DataFrame({'Eigen_value': eigen_values, 'Cumm_variance':eigen_values_cumvar}, index=range(1,23)).round(4)
```

[image: Result of the above code]

but when using factor analysis

```
fa = FactorAnalyzer(n_factors=10,rotation='varimax',method='ml').fit(credit_seg_new)
```

[image: I'm getting error]

please help as i'm stuck!!!

Comment: Please do not post pictures in SO. Try creating minimal reproducible codes and data here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i apologise for the trouble,but the starting two image were for the reference....please help

Comment: I would be glad to help. Please use the link in the provided comment to edit your post, so we can use your minimal reproducible code to fix the problem. Thank you.

Comment: i have gone through the link and it is just the instruction,so basically i have to ask the same question again and i have a question limit

Comment: You can edit this question. No need to create a new one. It is hard to help from pictures

Comment: hello i have made some changes as per your suggestion,please help

Comment: I hope it is understandable?

Comment: Please let me know what i'm missing as per your requirement..